# AVPlayer with Cloudflare

Tags: swift, avplayer, cloudflare

I am playing videos from url and it works well but now we are trying to switch to cloudflare and would need to handle the videos that are sent. The only problem now is every other video url works except a cloudflare url

how I am playing

```
let fileURL = URL(string: "https://watch.cloudflarestream.com/cb9618c34c4fbf6fa88bb48b73")
player = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL!)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
player!.play()
```

how can I make AVPlayer play cloudflare videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `m3u8` format and the full link will be like this
https://videodelivery.net/5d5bc37ffcf54c9b82e996823bffbb81/manifest/video.m3u8 where 5d5bc37ffcf54c9b82e996823bffbb81 - VideoID. This ID I took [from the browser source](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/video-playback/), but I can't play your example, perhaps you need to set some additional settings for your video to play. I mean videoID `cb9618c34c4fbf6fa88bb48b73`

You can test this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let fileURL = URL(string: "https://videodelivery.net/5d5bc37ffcf54c9b82e996823bffbb81/manifest/video.m3u8")
        player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay. How is `https://videodelivery.net` set up because thesis an enterprise application

Comment: @King as I understand, videodelivery.net is the place where video data is stored for cloudflare. I guess you can get more information in service support about it